# Union of finite connected subsets which intersect pairwise is connected proof verification

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

$X$ is a topological space and $A_1 ,\ldots ,A_n \subset X$ connected subsets such that $A_k  \cap  A_{k+1} \neq \emptyset$ for all $k = 1 ,\ldots ,n-1$. I must show that $A_1 \cap \ldots \cap A_n$ is connected. I am using proof by induction along with the fact that a space $(X,\tau)$ is connected $\iff$ when $f: X \longrightarrow \{0,1\}$ is continuous, it is constant. My attempt at a proof is as follows:

Assume $A_1 \cup A_2$ disconnected. Then, there exist two non-empty, disjoint and open subsets, say $B$ and $C$, such that $A_1 \cup A_2 = B \cup C$. Define $f: U \cup V \longrightarrow \{0,1\}$ by $$f(x)=\begin{cases}1& \; ; x\in U\\0&\; ; x\in V\end{cases}$$To show it is continuous, consider some open subset of $\{0,1\}$, say $W$. It is a simple case by case verification: $$\begin{array}{cc} 1) & 0 \notin W, 1 \notin W, f^{-1}(W) = \emptyset \\ 2) & 0 \in W, 1 \in W, f^{-1}(W) = A_1 \cup A_2 \\ 3) & 0 \in W, 1 \notin W, f^{-1}(W) = V \\ 4) & 0 \notin W, 1 \in W, f^{-1}(W) = U \end{array}$$
Thus, $f$ is continuous since $f^{-1}(W)$ is open whenever $W$ is open. Now, having proved our $f$ is continuous, we need to show it is constant. Indeed, since $A_1$ is connected, $f(A_1) = 0$ or $f(A_1) = 1.$ Say it equal to 0. Then, $f(A_1 \cap A_2) = 0$ since $A_1 \cap A_2 \subset A_1$ but since $A_2$ is also connected, this means that $f(A_2) = f(A_1 \cap A_2) = f(A_1) = 0$. It is the exact same if $f(A_1) = 1$. This gives us a contradiction to our initial assumption that $A_1 \cup A_2$ is disconnected which implies that it is indeed connected.

Assume the case is true for $A_k \cup A_{k+1}$. We will show it is true for $A_{k+1} \cup A_{(k+1)+1}$. Namely, if we proceed in the same fashion as for the trivial case, we will arrive at the point that $$f(A_{(k+1)+1}) = f(A_{k+1} \cap A_{(k+1)+1}) = f(A_{k+1}) = \text{constant}$$ where the constant is either $0$ or $1$. We may now disregard the intersection and apply our hypothesis, namely that $$f(A_{(k+1)+1}) = f(A_{k+1}) = f(A_k) = f(A_{k-1}) = \cdots = f(A_1) = \text{constant}$$ which shows that $A_1 \cup \cdots \cup A_n$ is indeed connected.

This does make sense to me but if there is anything wrong with it at all, please do let me know where I went wrong as I would like to try figure this out on my own. I appreciate any help given!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The theorem that you want to prove is that for every $n\in\Bbb Z^+$, $\bigcup_{k=1}^nA_k$ is connected if each of the sets $A_k$ is connected, and $A_k\cap A_{k+1}\ne\varnothing$ for $k=1,\ldots,n-1$. Since you’re trying to prove that something is true for each positive integer $n$, you should be inducting on $n$. The result is trivial for $n=1$. For the induction step we assume that the result is true for $n$ and try to prove it for $n+1$, so let $A_1,\ldots,A_{n+1}$ be connected subsets of $X$ such that $A_k\cap A_{k+1}\ne\varnothing$ for $k=1,\ldots,n$. Then

$$\bigcup_{k=1}^{n+1}A_k=\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^nA_k\right)\cup A_{n+1}\,.$$

For convenience let $A=\bigcup_{k=1}^nA_k$; by the induction hypothesis $A$ is connected, and clearly $A\cap A_{n+1}\supseteq A_n\cap A_{n+1}\ne\varnothing$. The argument that you used to show that $A_1\cup A_2$ is connected can easily be adapted to show that $A\cup A_{n+1}$ is connected, and that completes the induction step.